# How can I keep my scholarship when I am in danger of failing to meet GPA requirements?

Tags: graduate-school, funding, gpa

This year, I have started a mathematics graduate programm at a top level private university in my Country. I took 3 courses: Algebra 1, Analysis 1 and Commutative Algebra. During the semester, I have faced some problems, e.g. my family, and I could not able to work on my classes regularly. So, at the end, I will end up with getting a GPA about ***1.5/4***. The university provides a scholarship that includes my accommodation and monthly stipends. In order to keep this scholarship, my average GPA must not be below ***2.7*** for 2 semesters. So even if I take 3 or 4 courses and get ***4.0*** in the next semester, my GPA will be below ***2.7***. I believe sure that I can do better in the next semester.

So, what should I do? I really need some suggestions because I am very happy with the university, classes I take and the qualified lecturers.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to A.SE. Random strangers on the internet are not going to be able to help you with your problem. The best course of action would be to talk with your scholarship administrators; they may be able to work with you as you attempt to improve your performance in the coming term.

Comment: "So even if I take 3 or 4 courses and get 4.0 in the next semester, my GPA will be below 2.7." - I'm confused. If you got a 1.5 in your first semester and you take the same number of credits with a 4.0 your second semester, wouldn't you have a 2.75?

Comment: The courses I take this semester has 4,4 and 3 credits because 2 of them are compulsory. There is not any course in the second semester which has 4 credits. 

C- for a 4 credit and 3 credit course & D for a 4 credit course for the first semester gives us 1.45 GPA and if I take 3 courses in the second semester with 3 credits, my GPA will be 2.15 at the end of the year.

Comment: Uh... I'm pretty sure that arithmetic is wrong. If you carried a 1.509 GPA on 11 credits (4+4+3) and then you get a 4.0 on another 9 credits (3+3+3), you'll have a 2.63. If you could manage four classes your second semester and a 4.0, you'd have a 2.8 for the year. (Not that I think a 4.0 semester is very likely; but you should at least understand how close or far you are.)

Comment: Have you reached out to your university for support?

Comment: @Jeff, not yet, I am still at home.

Comment: Unless the average grades in those classes was C or lower (which would not be the case in graduate level classes in the U.S.), something is really wrong here.  Were you well prepared in foundational knowledge from your Bachelor's?  Was the grade largely or entirely based on exam performance?  Did you freeze up or have some unusual problem during the exams? // I would suggest that you document the family problems (and/or any health or mental health or caregiver challenges you may have faced during the semester), and try to withdraw from those classes. // There are some unsavory practices...

Comment: ...in some schools in the U.S., usually at the undergraduate level, involving admitting more students to a program than are objectively properly qualified, for the purpose of collecting more tuition income, from underprepared students who then end up dropping out.  So it would be good to know whether you were properly accepted to the program, and how much all this is costing. // The high level of engagement you showed suggests the difficulty may not lie entirely with you.

Answer (score 2):

First: Go **talk** to someone about this. Your advisor would be a good start. They will know the policies of your university better than us.

Second: You may be able to **replace** those grades by repeating the courses (you obviously need to anyway), in which case your GPA could potentially be 4.0 by the end of your next semester. This is how it worked at my undergrad but you'll have to check the policy at your university.

Comment: I am thinking to go to the Grad. School of Sciences about it. I have an advisor but he was so busy that we will not meet until the end of this semester. Unfortunately it may not be possible to replace those grades because the classes I take are Algebra 1, Analysis 1 and Commutative Algebra which is an elective course so they will not be available next semester.